# ¿Poner un sum en los filtros de una consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Buen día, estoy programando esta consulta:

```
SELECT t1.percod permisor, t1.pernom ciudad,
       t2.abocod cod_abonado, t2.abonom1 nombre, t2.aboape1 apellido,
       t2.abosts, t2.abocmsts, t2.abotlfsts, t2.aboipsts,
       t3.recicod, t3.recifch, t3.reciimp monto_recibo, 
       (t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp)) monto_sin_aplicar
FROM gx.permis t1,
     gx.abonad t2,
     gx.recibo t3,
     gx.recide t4
WHERE t1.percod = t2.percod
  AND t2.percod = t3.percod
  AND t2.abocod = t3.abocod
  AND t3.percod = t4.percod
  AND t3.recicod = t4.recicod
GROUP BY t1.percod, t1.pernom, t2.abocod, t2.abonom1, t2.aboape1, t2.abosts, t2.abocmsts,t2.abotlfsts, t2.aboipsts, t2.abodthsts, t3.recicod, t3.recifch, t3.reciimp;
```

Lo que necesito es que la consulta no muestre aquellos datos donde `(t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp))` sea igual a cero (0)... probé añadiendo 
`AND (t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp)) <> 0` pero da este error:

> ORA-00934: función de grupo no permitida aquí
>   00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error en la línea: 19, columna: 23

**¿como resuelvo ese error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz una query que devuelva la diferencia entre esos dos campos y filtra por ella. Algo así:

```
select * from (SELECT t1.percod permisor, t1.pernom ciudad,
       t2.abocod cod_abonado, t2.abonom1 nombre, t2.aboape1 apellido,
       t2.abosts, t2.abocmsts, t2.abotlfsts, t2.aboipsts,
       t3.recicod, t3.recifch, t3.reciimp monto_recibo, 
       (t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp)) monto_sin_aplicar,
       (t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp)) diferencia
FROM gx.permis t1,
     gx.abonad t2,
     gx.recibo t3,
     gx.recide t4
WHERE t1.percod = t2.percod
  AND t2.percod = t3.percod
  AND t2.abocod = t3.abocod
  AND t3.percod = t4.percod
      AND t3.recicod = t4.recicod
    GROUP BY t1.percod, t1.pernom, t2.abocod, t2.abonom1, t2.aboape1, t2.abosts, t2.abocmsts,
t2.abotlfsts, t2.aboipsts, t2.abodthsts, t3.recicod, t3.recifch, t3.reciimp)
    where diferencia=0;
```

Comment: Gracias, eso lo resolvió.

Answer (score 1):

El estándar SQL incluye la clausula **`having`**, que sirve para filtrar el resultado de una consulta luego de haber agrupado.

Si bien la [respuesta de pablo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47376/21) te da una solución, en mi humilde opinión, es más difícil de interpretar y de darle mantenimiento.

Prueba con esto:

```
select   t1.percod permisor
       , t1.pernom ciudad
       , t2.abocod cod_abonado
       , t2.abonom1 nombre
       , t2.aboape1 apellido
       , t2.abosts
       , t2.abocmsts
       , t2.abotlfsts
       , t2.aboipsts
       , t3.recicod
       , t3.recifch
       , t3.reciimp monto_recibo
       , (t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp)) monto_sin_aplicar
  from gx.permis t1
       inner join gx.abonad t2 on t1.percod = t2.percod
       inner join gx.recibo t3 on t2.percod = t3.percod and t2.abocod = t3.abocod
       inner join gx.recide t4 on t3.percod = t4.percod and t3.recicod = t4.recicod
 group by  t1.percod
       , t1.pernom
       , t2.abocod
       , t2.abonom1
       , t2.aboape1
       , t2.abosts
       , t2.abocmsts
       , t2.abotlfsts
       , t2.aboipsts
       , t2.abodthsts
       , t3.recicod
       , t3.recifch
       , t3.reciimp
having t3.reciimp - sum(t4.recifacimp) != 0;
```

Me he tomado la libertad de re-escribir tu query utilizando la sintaxis **`join`** del SQL 92, puesto que creo que también ayuda a dejar claro que condiciones son para relacionar tablas y cuáles serían para filtrar registros.

A menos que utilizaras una versión muy vieja de Oracle, no vas a tener problemas con él.

Comment: Gracias por el dato, también funciona.